# Limits to infinite

Tags: limits

$$20.\quad \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-6}{5x\sqrt[3]x} = -\frac65\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{x^{4/3}}= -\frac65\cdot 0 = 0$$

([Original scan of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTvSO.jpg))

I cant figure out how to resolve this problem.

I would say that denominator tends to infinite and limit of -6 / infinite is 0. However the book seems to follow another way. Can you explain please?

Comment: The denominator grows without bound while the numerator remains fixed at $-6$. Hence the limit is zero.

Comment: What you say is true and the book has just taken out $-\frac{6}{5}$ out of the limits because it's just a constant.

Comment: But I am NOT happy with the approach the book did for Q21 !!! Frankly speaking, quite upset...

Comment: @imranfat Ha ha, I guess L'hopital should have been the best description for that ! The book's answer seems to be quite arbitrary.

Comment: @Sudarsan: You don't even need L'Hopital. Divide top and bottom by $x$.

Comment: Sudarsan and Michael, you are both correct and considering the 3 problems I suspect that they may not know L'Hospital yet, and so Michael's method would then be appropriate, but not the way how the book presented it. Jorge, take a note of Michael's remark when you move on to Q21

Comment: @Jorge: Just to be clear, the word you should be using here is infinity, not infinite. Infinity is a noun, infinite is an adjective.

Comment: I think the 21 is just taking the most representative X.

Comment: Yes Jorge, that is true. But the way how they "knocked off" the constants is not right. Dividing every term by x (which is the leading term as you mentioned) and then take the limit, is the appropriate way. Problems like this where x goes to infinity come back with radicals in the fraction and then taking off the constants will likely go wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book does exactly what you said, except for the fact that they first take out the constant $-\dfrac{6}{5}$.

---

**Regarding your comments:** One of the index laws is that $x^ax^b = x^{a+b}$. Together with the fact that for any positive integer $n$, $x^{\frac{1}{n}} = \sqrt[n]{x}$, you can get the desired denominator.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate a step by step resolution sorry its just I still cant get it.

Comment: What is confusing me is that I tried to reach X 4/3 and didnt make it.

Comment: $x x^{\frac{1}{3}} =x^1 x^{\frac{1}{3}} = x^{\frac{3}{3}}x^{\frac{1}{3}} = x^{\frac{3}{3}+\frac{1}{3}}=x^{\frac{4}{3}}$.